# Numeric Variable has 20 observations that won't merge because they are "factor"

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, factors

I have two dataframes with two variables, date and count1 and date and count2. Date is numeric. I want to merge on date keeping dates that only have one count observation (either a count1 or a count2).

```
> class(totals$date)
[1] "numeric"
> totals$date <- as.numeric(totals$date)
> news.prop <- merge(ME_StoryCount,totals,by="date",all = T)
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(20110104, 20110105, 20110106,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

This gives a data frame with the majority of the observations merged except for about 20 of the 102. Please help...

Comment: Is `ME_StoryCount$date` numeric? If not, just `ME_StoryCount$date<-as.numeric(as.character(ME_StoryCount$date)`

Comment: Yes, it's numeric as well.